# What is the resort of Nibbaana?

Tags: pali-canon, nirvana

In [Unnabho Brahmano Sutta: The Brahman Unnabha](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn48/sn48.042.wlsh.html)  says

> "There are, Brahman, these five sense-faculties... which do not share
>   in each other's sphere of action. Mind is their resort, and it is mind
>   that profits from their combined activity."
>
> "But, good Gotama, what is mind's resort?"
>
> "Mind's resort, Brahman, is mindfulness."[4]
>
> "Then, good Gotama, what is the resort of mindfulness?"[5]
>
> "The resort of mindfulness, Brahman, is liberation."
>
> "Then, good Gotama, what is the resort of liberation?"
>
> "The resort of liberation is Nibbaana."
>
> "Then, good Gotama, what is the resort of Nibbaana?"
>
> "That question goes too far Brahman. No answer can encompass it. The
>   aim of the holy life, Brahman, is immersion[6] in Nibbaana, it has
>   Nibbaana for its final end, Nibbaana for its conclusion."

Is this suttha says Nibbaana resort on five seance faculties?  or If Not how can it seance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, "resort" is a bad translation for `patisaranam` (literally, something other things rest on) -- a better option in this particular context would be "apex". Compare with following simile from Milindapanha:

> Like in a building with a pointed roof: whatever rafters they are, they all rest on the apex, lean towards the apex, meet at the apex, and the apex is pointed to as their chief. So is the *samadhi* in its relation to the other wholesome dharmas.

It does make more sense this way, doesn't it:

> **Brahman Unnabha**: As the five faculties are of different scope and range, and do not share in each other's sphere of action, what is their *apex*, and who profits from their combined activity?
>
> **Buddha**: Mind is their apex, and it is mind that profits from their combined activity.
>
> **B.U.**: But, good Gotama, what is mind's apex?
>
> **B**: Mind's apex, Brahman, is mindfulness.
>
> **B.U.**: Then, good Gotama, what is the apex of mindfulness?
>
> **B**: The apex of mindfulness, Brahman, is liberation.
>
> **B.U.**: Then, good Gotama, what is the apex of liberation?
>
> **B**: The apex of liberation is Nirvana.
>
> **B.U.**: Then, good Gotama, what is the apex of Nirvana?
>
> **B**: That question goes too far, Brahman.

Answer (score 1):

> "That question goes too far Brahman. No answer can encompass it. The
>   aim of the holy life, Brahman, is immersion[6] in Nibbaana, it has
>   Nibbaana for its final end, Nibbaana for its conclusion."